# How to store array within dictionary

Tags: ios

How to store an array within a dictionary in Objective-C. How do I have to modify my code?

```
studentDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
studentArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[studentArray addObject:name.text];
[studentArray addObject:regno.text];
[studentArray addObject:marks.text];
[studentArray addObject:rank.text];
studentDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:studentArray, nil] forKeys:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:studentArray, nil]];
NSLog(@"%@",studentArray);
```

Comment: `NSDictionary *studentsDictionary = @{@"students": studentArray};`

Answer (score 1):

Stick to variable name, it makes your code readable and less-prone to errors.
If you have an array named "studentArray" then it should only store objects of `Student` class.

```
    Student *firstStudent = ....;
    Student *secondStudent = .... ;
    NSArray *studentArray = @[firstStudent, secondStudent];
```

Now you want to store this array in a dictionary:

```
NSDictioanary *someDictionary = @{@"studentArrayKey" : studentArray
                                         @"otherKey" : @"otherObject",
                                 };
```

Edit:

It would be nice if you name `studentArray` to `students` as per Obj-C naming conventions. All collection sounds good when named plural.

Comment: @JAGAT: I updated, I believe you are well aware of the Edit part.